# GNU make rearrange PDF document for 4on1 printing

Tags: pdf, printing, makefile

I have a PDF document `cards.pdf` that I want to print with the 4on1 twoside printer settings. I use a GNU makefile to create the document, so that's where I'm looking for solutions.

Four pages will be printed on one to save paper (and a6 actually is my desired paper for the cards) and some pages will be printed on the back. However, I also want to be able to flip the pages to find the correct back after cutting the paper. I understand that I need to rearrange the pages according to this order:

```
1  3  5  7 4 2 8 6 
9 11 13 15 ...
```

I can use `pdftk` to do this but there are problems:

1. The number of pages of the document `cards.pdf` is unknown.
2. The number of pages of `cards.pdf` is not necessarily a multiple of 8.
3. The size of the rearranged document bloats. (from 338kB to 1.6MB in my example with 91 pages)

---

I'm looking for an easy to handle GNU make solution to rearrange the pages without bloating the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a partial GNU make and partial C solution. I checked it for a 400 page document and there was no bloat. If this is satisfactory, the C program can be re-written as a shell script and embedded into the makefile.

My understanding is that the problem consists of generating the correct sequence of page numbers for `pdftk`. I have written a small (< 70lines) C program, called print_order.c to generate that sequence. And, I have modified the `makefile` to use it.

**print_order.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int pg_eight [] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6};

const char* blank_page = "B1";

void advance_pg_eight()
{
    int j=0;
    for(j=0; j < 8; j++)
        pg_eight[j] += 8;
}

void print_pg_eight (long int npages)
{
    int j=0;
    static int nprinted = 0;
    for (j=0; j < 8 && nprinted < npages; j++) {
        if(pg_eight[j] > npages)
            printf("%4s ", blank_page);
        else 
        {
            printf("%4d ", pg_eight[j]);
            nprinted++;
        }
    }
}

long int get_npages(const char *first_arg)
{
    char *endptr = "Hello";
    long int npages = strtol(first_arg, &endptr, 10);

    if (*endptr != '\0' || npages <= 0)
        return 0;

    return npages;
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    long int npages = 0;
    int neights = 0, j=0;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Insufficient number of arguments\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }
    npages = get_npages(argv[1]);
    if (0 == npages) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Failed to parse number of pages (%s)\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        return 0;
    }

    neights = npages/8;
    if (npages % 8 != 0)
        neights++;

    for(j = 0; j < neights; j++) {
        print_pg_eight(npages);
        advance_pg_eight();
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

**Modified `makefile`**

```
#
# use a shell escape to get the number of pages of the pdf file with:
# qpdf --show-npages ./cards.pdf
NPAGES := $(shell qpdf --show-npages ./cards.pdf)
#
PRINT := $(shell ./print_order $(NPAGES))

print.pdf: makefile cards.pdf blank.pdf print_order
    pdftk B=blank.pdf cards.pdf cat $(PRINT) output print.pdf

print_order: print_order.c
```

A sample output of `print_order` for 91 pages:

```
1    3    5    7    4    2    8    6 
9   11   13   15   12   10   16   14 
17   19   21   23   20   18   24   22 
25   27   29   31   28   26   32   30 
33   35   37   39   36   34   40   38 
41   43   45   47   44   42   48   46 
49   51   53   55   52   50   56   54 
57   59   61   63   60   58   64   62 
65   67   69   71   68   66   72   70 
73   75   77   79   76   74   80   78 
81   83   85   87   84   82   88   86 
89   91   B1   B1   B1   90
```

`B1` is the first page of a pdf with a blank first page.

To use this solution:

1. Copy above C code to create `print_order.c`
2. Copy a pdf with a blank first page as `blank.pdf`
3. Copy the pdf that should be re-ordered as `cards.pdf`
4. Run `make`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am trying to get your solution to work. First, it looks like it's missing the directive to build print_order: `gcc print_order.c -o print_order`

Comment: Secondly, at least on my machine, I have to rearrange the `pdftk` command to `pdftk cards.pdf B=blank.pdf cat $(PRINT) output print.pdf`.
This is because pages without handle refer to the first input file. Quoting from `pdftk`'s help:  If the handle is omitted from the page range, then the pages are taken from the first input PDF.

Answer (score 0):

The following makefile does what I want in a very bad way I guess. I add an empty page at the beginning of the document for convenience.

`qpdf` is used to get the number of pages of `cards.pdf`.
The rule `PG_EIGHT` is used to expand to a block of 8 pages in the correct order for printing.

```
# declare following rule with = only, no := 
PG_EIGHT = $$((8*$(1)+2)) $$((8*$(1)+4)) $$((8*$(1)+6)) $$((8*$(1)+8)) $$((8*$(1)+5)) $$((8*$(1)+3)) $$((8*$(1)+9)) $$((8*$(1)+7)) 
#
# use a shell escape to get the number of pages of the pdf file with:
# qpdf --show-npages ./cards.pdf
PG_MAX := $$(( $(shell qpdf --show-npages ./cards.pdf) -1 ))
#
#division discards remainder:
BLOCKS := $(shell seq 0 $$(($(PG_MAX) / 8  - 1))) 
PRINT := $(foreach BLOCK,$(BLOCKS),$(call PG_EIGHT,$(BLOCK)))
#
# get the rest (remainder) of the pages with modulo division:
PG_RM := $(shell echo $(PG_MAX)%8 | bc)
# get last page of last BLOCK:
PG_MAX := $$(( $(PG_MAX) - $(PG_RM) ))
#
# do nothing if remainder is 0.
ifeq ($(PG_RM),1)
PRINT += $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 2))
else ifeq ($(PG_RM),2)
PRINT += $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 2)) 0 0 0 0 $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 3))
else ifeq ($(PG_RM),3)
PRINT += $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 2)) $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 4)) 0 0 0 $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 2))
else ifeq ($(PG_RM),4)
PRINT += $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 2)) $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 4)) 0 0 $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 5)) $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 3)) 
else ifeq ($(PG_RM),5)
PRINT += $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 2)) $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 4)) $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 6)) 0 $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 5)) $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 3)) 
else ifeq ($(PG_RM),6)
PRINT += $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 2)) $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 4)) $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 6)) 0 $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 5)) $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 3)) 0 $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 7))
else ifeq ($(PG_RM),7)
PRINT += $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 2)) $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 4)) $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 6)) $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 8)) $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 5)) $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 3)) 0 $$(( $(PG_MAX) + 7))
# remainder cannot be equal to 8.
endif

# fully evaluate the PRINT string:
PRINT := $(shell echo $(PRINT))

print.pdf: makefile cards.pdf
    echo $(BLOCKS)
    pdftk cards.pdf cat $(PRINT) output print.pdf
```

What is terrible about this code is the handling of the remainder and the frequent shell escapes.

I don't understand why it bloats the filesize, though.